# R: How can I replace let's say the 5th element within a string?

Tags: string, r, replace

I would like to convert the a string like be33szfuhm100060 into BESZFUHM0060.

In order to replace the small letters with capital letters I've so far used the gsub function.

```
test1=gsub("be","BE",test)
```

Is there a way to tell this function to replace the 3rd and 4th string element? If not, I would really appreciate if you could tell me another way to solve this problem. Maybe there is also a more general solution to change a string element at a certain position into a capital letter whatever the element is?

Comment: Just use `toupper` if you want all the letters to be uppercase.

Comment: thanks, easy enough. Hopefully somebody also has a solution for my actual problem.

Comment: `toupper` is what you need but for problem state in title solution is: `sub("^(.{4})(.)(.*$)", "\\15\\3", "abcdef")` which gives `"abcd5f"`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A couple of observations:

Cnverting a string to uppercase can be done with `toupper`, e.g.:

```
> toupper('be33szfuhm100060')
> [1] "BE33SZFUHM100060"
```

You could use `substr` to extract a substring by character positions and `paste` to concatenate strings:

```
> x <- 'be33szfuhm100060'
> paste(substr(x, 1, 2), substr(x, 5, nchar(x)), sep='')
[1] "beszfuhm100060"
```

Answer (score 7):

As an alternative, if you are going to be doing this alot:

```
String <- function(x="") {
  x <- as.character(paste(x, collapse=""))
  class(x) <- c("String","character")
  return(x)
}

"[.String" <- function(x,i,j,...,drop=TRUE) {
  unlist(strsplit(x,""))[i]
}
"[<-.String" <- function(x,i,j,...,value) {
  tmp <- x[]
  tmp[i] <- String(value)
  x <- String(tmp)
  x
}
print.String <- function(x, ...) cat(x, "\n")
## try it out
> x <- String("be33szfuhm100060")
> x[3:4] <- character(0)
> x
beszfuhm100060
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use `substring` to remove the third and fourth elements.

```
x <- "be33szfuhm100060"
paste(substring(x, 1, 2), substring(x, 5), sep = "")
```

Answer (score 0):

If you know what portions of the string you want based on their position(s), use `substr` or `substring`.  As I mentioned in my comment, you can use `toupper` to coerce characters to uppercase.

```
paste( toupper(substr(test,1, 2)),
       toupper(substr(test,5,10)),
       substr(test,12,nchar(test)),sep="")
# [1] "BESZFUHM00060"
```