# Delete characters at positions within a string in R?

Tags: string, r, character

I am looking for a way to delete the characters at certain positions within a string in R. For example, if we have a string `"1,2,1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1"`, I want to delete the third, fourth, 7th and 8th position. The operation would make the string: `"1,1,2,1,1,1,1,2,1,1"`.

Unfortunately, breaking the string into a list using strsplit is not an option, because the strings I am working with are over 1 million characters long. Considering I have about 2,500 strings, it works out to be quite some time.

Alternatively, finding a way to replace the characters with an empty string `""` would achieve the same purpose - I think. Looking into this line of thought, I came across this StackOverflow post:

[R: How can I replace let's say the 5th element within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819573/r-how-can-i-replace-lets-say-the-5th-element-within-a-string)

Unfortunately, the solution suggested is hard to efficiently generalize and the following takes about 60 seconds per input string for a list of 2000 positions to remove:

```
subchar2 = function(inputstring, pos){
string = ""
memory = 0
for(num in pos){
    string = paste(string, substr(inputstring, (memory+1), (num-1)), sep = "")
    memory = num
}
string = paste(string, substr(inputstring,(memory+1), nchar(inputstring)),sep = "")
return(string)
}
```

Looking into the problem, I found a snippet of code, that seems to replace the characters at certain positions with `"-"`:

```
subchar <- function(string, pos) {
        for(i in pos) {
            string <- gsub(paste("^(.{", i-1, "}).", sep=""), "\\1-", string)
        }
        return(string)
}
```

I don't quite understand regular expression (yet), but I have a strong suspicion something along these lines will be much better time-wise than the first code solution. Unfortunately, this subchar function seems to break when the values in pos gets high:

```
> test = subchar(data[1], 257)
Error in gsub(paste("^(.{", i - 1, "}).", sep = ""), "\\1-", string) :
invalid regular expression '^(.{256}).', reason 'Invalid contents of {}'
```

I was also considering trying to read in the string data into a table using SQL, but I was hoping that there would be a elegant string solution. The SQL implementation in R to do this seems rather complicated.

Any ideas?
Thanks!

Comment: Where are the strings coming from in the first place? It might be easier to preprocess the data in something other than R.

Comment: The strings come from an .RData file, but I can quickly write it out to a text file, so that opens the scope. Any language suggestions?

Comment: Are they always comma separately numbers? If so, wouldn't it be easier to convert them each to a vector, subset, and then convert back to character? Then you can just use numerical indexing to drop elements.

Comment: Yes, they are always comma seperated. Unfortunately, as stated in the post, strsplit() takes really long for strings over a million character. Is there a fast way to the conversion to a vector?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`strsplit` is more than ten times faster if you use `fixed = TRUE`. Rough extrapolation and it will take a little over 2 minutes to process your 2,500 strings of 1,000,000 comma separated integers.

```
N <- 1000000
x <- sample(0:1, N, replace = TRUE)
s <- paste(x, collapse = ",")

# this is a vector of 10 strings
M <- 10
S <- rep(s, M)

system.time(y <- strsplit(S, split = ","))
# user  system elapsed 
# 6.57    0.00    6.56 
system.time(y <- strsplit(S, split = ",", fixed = TRUE))
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.46    0.03    0.50
```

This is almost 3 times faster than using scan:

```
system.time(scan(textConnection(S), sep=",", what="a"))
# Read 10000000 items
# user  system elapsed 
# 1.21    0.09    1.42
```

Comment: Fastest solution. And happy data in R now!

Comment: The entire data processing just finished. The estimate should be pushed to a few hours.

Answer (score 3):

Read them in using `scan()`. You can set the separator to be "," and what="a". You can `scan` one "line" at a time with `nlines=1` and if it is a `textConnection`, the "pipeline" will "remember" where it was as of the last read.

```
x <- paste( sample(0:1, 1000, rep=T), sep=",")
xin <- textConnection(x)

x995 <- scan(xin, sep=",", what="a", nmax=995)
# Read 995 items
x5 <- scan(xin, sep=",", what="a", nmax=995)
# Read 5 items
```

Here's an illustration with 5 "lines"

```
> x <- paste( rep( paste(sample(0:1, 50, rep=T), collapse=","),  5),  collapse="\n")
> str(x)
 chr "1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0\n1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,"| __truncated__
> xin <- textConnection(x)
> x1 <- scan(xin, sep=",", what="a", nlines=1)
Read 50 items
> x2 <- scan(xin, sep=",", what="a", nlines=1)
Read 50 items
> x3 <- scan(xin, sep=",", what="a", nlines=1)
Read 50 items
> x4 <- scan(xin, sep=",", what="a", nlines=1)
Read 50 items
> x5 <- scan(xin, sep=",", what="a", nlines=1)
Read 50 items
> x6 <- scan(xin, sep=",", what="a", nlines=1)
Read 0 items
> length(x1)
[1] 50
> length(x1[-c(3,4,7,8)])
[1] 46
> paste(x1, collapse=",")
[1] "1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,0"
>
```

Answer (score 2):

One quick speed fix is to remove the pastes in the for loop

```
subchar3<-function(inputstring, pos){
string = ""
memory = 0
for(num in pos){
    string = c(string,substr(inputstring, (memory+1), (num-1)))
    memory = num
}
string = paste(c(string, substr(inputstring,(memory+1), nchar(inputstring))),collapse = "")
return(string)
}
data<-paste(sample(letters,100000,replace=T),collapse='')
remove<-sample(1:nchar(data),200)
remove<-remove[order(remove)]
s2<-subchar2(data,remove)
s3<-subchar3(data,remove)
identical(s2,s3)
#[1] TRUE

> library(rbenchmark)
> benchmark(subchar2(data,remove),subchar3(data,remove),replications=10)
                    test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self
1 subchar2(data, remove)           10   43.64 40.78505     39.97      1.9
2 subchar3(data, remove)           10    1.07  1.00000      1.01      0.0
  user.child sys.child
1         NA        NA
2         NA        NA
```

Comment: Wow, I just implemented this and so far its great! Thanks. I find the improvement pretty curious.