# Replace first element of a string in R based on a condition

Tags: r, string, substring

I want to replace the first element of the strings in x with blank if it satisfies the  condition : If first element of "101" in x matches the first string in y, replace first element of "101" with blank.

```
x = c("101", "201", "301")
y = c("1", "7", "3")
```

Want:

```
> x
[1] "01" "201" "01"
```

I was trying:

```
> ifelse(substr(x, 1, 1) == y, sub(substr(x, 1, 1), ""), x)
```

I know this is wrong though not intuitively- `sub` needs a pattern as first argument and won't take `substr`.

Also tried :

```
> ifelse(substr(x, 1, 1) == y, substr(x, 1, 1) <- "", x)
[1] ""    "201" ""
```

I referred this [R: How can I replace let's say the 5th element within a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6819573/r-how-can-i-replace-lets-say-the-5th-element-within-a-string) and solved it using :

```
ifelse(substr(x, 1, 1) == y, paste(substr(x, 2, nchar(x))), x)
```

wondering if there is a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The regex to match the first character is `"^."` (`^` is start of string, `.` is any single character), so use `sub` just like you suggest:

```
ifelse(substr(x, 1, 1) == y, sub("^.", "", x), x)
# [1] "01"  "201" "01"
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't know if it's better, but you could always use `mapply()` in a situation like this:

```
x <- c("apple", "bog", "cat", "dog")
y <- c('a', 'b', 'b', 'd')

logi <- mapply(`==`, substr(x,1,1), y)

substr(x[logi],1,1) <- ""
 x
[1] "pple" "og"   "cat"  "og"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `stri_sub` from `stringi` package:

```
x = c("101", "201", "301")
y = c("1", "7", "3")
require(stringi)
stri_sub(x, 1 + (stri_sub(x, 1,1)==y))
## [1] "01"  "201" "01"
```

Some benchmarks:

```
require(microbenchmark)
x <- stri_rand_strings(1000, 20, "[0-9]")
head(x)
## [1] "54144716481937965959" "85386002944985867089" "30205714375670945562" "81644306435633236981"
[5] "88781777748301517606" "13505496126231808763"
## y <- stri_rand_strings(1000, 1, "[0-9]")
head(y)
## [1] "1" "4" "3" "8" "4" "9"
microbenchmark(stri_sub(x, 1 + (stri_sub(x, 1,1)==y)), ifelse(substr(x, 1, 1) == y, sub("^.", "", x), x), substr(x[mapply(`==`, substr(x,1,1), y)],1,1) <- "")
Loading required namespace: multcomp
Unit: microseconds


                                             expr      min        lq      mean    median       uq      max neval
               stri_sub(x, 1 + (stri_sub(x, 1, 1) == y))  154.876  160.4045  201.5347  198.4005  235.128  361.477   100
       ifelse(substr(x, 1, 1) == y, sub("^.", "", x), x)  424.915  434.1080  493.5478  446.9575  463.251 1666.774   100
 substr(x[mapply(`==`, substr(x, 1, 1), y)], 1, 1) <- "" 4169.437 4272.4095 4590.1717 4476.1615 4673.802 7278.571   100
```

Comment: Nice trick with adding the boolean value to `from` parameter!