# Replace first characters in a dataframe column with string data in R

Tags: r, gsub

I have the following sample dataframe:

```
df = data.frame(IDENTIFIER=c("1, 12131, 1995","1234, 5678"), STATE=c("NY","CA"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

my goal is to take all the strings in column IDENTIFIER and delete the initial two characters if they are equal to "1," without deleting all the other "1," instances within each string.
So for example, the desired output in this case would be:

```
df_new = data.frame(IDENTIFIER=c("12131, 1995","1234, 5678"), STATE=c("NY","CA"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Notice how in the first row I don't want to delete (gsub) the "1," string contained between "1213" and " 1995".
The difficulty I face is how to perform this operation on the column a big dataframe with thousand of rows.
I found the following post [Replace first element of a string in R based on a condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28866317/replace-first-element-of-a-string-in-r-based-on-a-condition) but I can't figure out how to apply to my specific need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R you could just use `sub` since you only want to replace the first instance.

```
df$IDENTIFIER <- sub("^1, ", "", df$IDENTIFIER)
```

`gsub` is "global sub" as in it will replace all instances without additional regex anchors. `sub` only replaces the first occurrence

Edit: although `sub("1, ", "", df$IDENTIFIER)` will work in your test data, @nrp1000 rightly points out the issue may arise in situations (ie, no leading 1, but a trailing "xxx1, yyyy"), so `^’ secures the start of the string.

Output:

```
#    IDENTIFIER STATE
# 1 12131, 1995    NY
# 2  1234, 5678    CA
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `^` with `gsub` to only replace 1 values that appear at the beginning of the string:

```
df <- data.frame(IDENTIFIER=c("1, 12131, 1995","1234, 5678"), STATE=c("NY","CA"), stringsAsFactors = F)
df_new <- data.frame(IDENTIFIER=c("12131, 1995","1234, 5678"), STATE=c("NY","CA"), stringsAsFactors = F)
all.equal(df, df_new) # "Component “IDENTIFIER”: 1 string mismatch"
df$IDENTIFIER <- gsub("^1, ", "", df$IDENTIFIER) # Remove values = 1 only if they appear at the beginning of the string
all.equal(df, df_new) # TRUE
```

For more details on how this works, see the anchors section of the R [regular expressions documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/stringr/vignettes/regular-expressions.html#anchors).